# Handlebars: query and sum

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I add the desired fields in a `mongo` `subdocument` in handlebars?

For example if my array is:

```
var fruits=[{ _id: 1, fruit: 'banana', number: 1 },{ _id: 2, fruit: 'Apple', number: 1 }]
```

and I want to add all the `numbers` together by doing something like this:

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
defaultLayout: 'mainlayout',
helpers: {
    addfruit: function(fruit){
        var addfruit="";
        for (each fruit){
            addfruit+=fruit.number;
            return addfruit;
        }
    },
};
```

My html:

```
<div><p>You have {{addfruit fruits}} in your fridge</p></div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is "fruit" in addfruit:function(fruit) ? Is that the array of results ?

Comment: yes. Am passing in the `fruits` array through `{{addfruit fruits}}`

Comment: @chidram 's answer should work in that case

Answer (score 3):

In your helper function, use the JavaScript **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method to sum the `number` field of the objects in the `fruits` array, something like the following should suffice:

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'mainlayout',
    helpers: {
        getTotal: function (fruits){
            var total = fruits.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b.number; }, 0);
            return total;
        }   
    }
});
```

And then in your html:

```
<div><p>You have {{getTotal fruits}} in your fridge</p></div>
```

Comment: am getting `total=NaN`

Comment: You are receiving this because there are some fruits objects that don't have a `number` field or the field can be null. You may need to check for the existence of the field within the reduce function body.

Comment: All my fruit objects have a number field. However it seems to be failing if there are more or less than 2 arrays in the list. If there are no arrays in the list it returns a `Reduce of empty array with no initial value` error. If there is 1 array, it returns the whole array. If there are 3 or more it returns a NaN value. Is there anyway to make this work for an indeterminable number of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
 getTotal: function(fruit){

        var myfruit = fruit.map(function(item) {
            return item.length;
        });

        var total=myfruit.reduce(function(prev,curr){
            return prev+curr},0);
        return total;   
 }
```